# Class in NPM Package. Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, babeljs

I've created an npm package and one of the libraries include "Employee.js" that looks like:

```
class Employee{
    name = null
}
```

In the package.json of the npm package I've put

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  },
```

and I have these babel dependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.9"
  }
```

Whenever I try to run this within electron I get this error

```
./node_modules/xxx/xxx/Employee.js
Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled:

> 6 |     name = null


Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4yQ) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

How do I make it so that I can have a class definition in a file and it not cause this issue when importing the package?

Thank You.